# Rails 406 error on respond_to block

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a "406 Not Acceptable in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)" error when I tried to implement ajax. Code works in normal html without any `respond_to` blocks. I've narrowed down the issue to the `respond_to` blocks and I'm stumped now. None of the other solutions on SO & google of the same error seem to apply or work.

1. What causes a 406 error when using the `respond_to` block whether html only or ajax/js included?
2. How to fix the 406 error?
3. Is it ok to use `redirect_to` in the `respond_to` block for `format.html` as shown in code below?

Let me know if you need more info.

**View (haml):**

Normal html code

```
%div.control-group.controls
  = button_to "Delete Gcal User", @gcal_user, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger"
```

AJAX code

```
%div.control-group.controls
  = button_to "Delete Gcal User", @gcal_user, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-danger"
```

JS code (coffeescript) for AJAX

```
$('#calendar').empty();
```

**Controller:**

```
class GcalUsersController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @gcal_user = current_user.gcal_user
    # if @gcal_user.delete
    #   flash[:notice] = "#{@gcal_user.username} deleted"
    # end

    # redirect_to user_root_path  # <-- using this in html mode, app works i.e. no 406 error

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(user_root_path) }  # <-- using this in html mode instead of above line, app fails i.e. 406 error
      # format.js  # <-- using this in ajax mode, app fails i.e. 406 error
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by routes. Using the singular `resource :gcal_user` instead of the plural `resources :gcal_users` caused the URL to be formated differently. The singular resource uses the "/gcal_user.[id]" which caused the `respond_to` block to think the format must be in ".[id]" instead of the ".js" or ".html".

See [Respond_to does not redirect, gives 406 Not Acceptable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306707/respond-to-does-not-redirect-gives-406-not-acceptable-error)

Answer (score 0):

You want to respond with "json", not with "js" (which means JavaScript here). `jquery_ujs`, the gem that adds the functionality for `method: :delete`, expects JSON.

```
def destroy
  @gcal_user = current_user.gcal_user
  @gcal_user.delete

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to user_root_path }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried but didn't work.  2 things: none of the ajax examples mention I need to use JSON or the query_ujs gem so I think it should work with JS only, and second, why doesn't the `format.html` (without JSON or JS) work in the non-ajax (i.e. html) version?

Comment: method: :delete requires the jquery_ujs gem. Your endpoint expects a DELETE request, which is not possible with a standard link. Links only send GET requests. You can wrap the button in a form with method="delete" for the same effect.

Comment: I see what you're saying. It seems jquery_ujs gem is already installed automatically in query-rails gem and I confirm both the web pages and application.js file have the jquery_ujs filename. Bare with me please as I want to understand what's going on, could you explain why using `redirect user_root_path` works in the controller but using `respond_to do |format| format.html { redirect_to user_root_path } end` does NOT work for the NORMAL HTML-NO AJAX button code?

Comment: Using `redirect user_root_path` immediately responds without first checking the requested format. It could request any format, and that redirect call would work. There is no "normal HTML-no Ajax" mode here. DELETE in Rails _requires_ JavaScript on a regular button. You could wrap the button in a `<form>` to prevent having to use JS.

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://eftakhairul.com/rails-3-no-route-matches-error-and-_method/ Otherwise try searching for "rails delete requests" to see what fits your situation best.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand what you're saying now and read up on it. I still can't get it to work on my app even wrapping it in a form or changing button to a link. I tried the `respond_to` block on Hartl's blog app and it worked. I'm not seeing any difference between the 2 apps but I'll keep trying.