# Respond_to does not redirect, gives 406 Not Acceptable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My `respond_to` block does not redirect back to the '/dashboard' view (url stays at 'gcal_user.19') and results in a "406 Not Acceptable" error when I click on the delete link in the dashboard view. Tried debugging, googling, stack overflow but all efforts been fruitless.

Using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3
The app includes jquery and jquery_ujs (unobtrusive js) in application.js

Dashboard View (Haml):

```
%div.control-group.controls
  = link_to "Delete Gcal User", @gcal_user, method: :delete
```

GcalUser Controller:

```
  def destroy
    @gcal_user = current_user.gcal_user

    # -- commented out for debugging --
    # if @gcal_user.delete
    #   flash[:notice] = "#{@gcal_user.username} deleted"
    # end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_root_path }
    end
  end
```

config/routes.rb

```
  get "home/index"
  root :to => 'home#index' #, as: '/'
  devise_for :users
  resource :gcal_user
  match "dashboard" => 'home#dashboard', as: :user_root
```

Route:

```
DELETE /gcal_user(.:format)              gcal_users#destroy
```

Clicking on the Delete link correctly reaches the `destroy` method. The issue occurs with the `respond_to` block.

Other code samples seem to have this working... I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any ideas?

Second, the 406 error is due to a request type mismatch, I believe, how do I check the type of the request and response being generated? If there is a mismatch, where in the code would I be able to change the request type?

Comment: in which route u are getting problem, link_to "Delete Gcal User" or user_root_path. Check if request goes to destroy action after clicking on 'Delete Gcal User' link ?

Comment: The request goes to the destroy action as expected. I narrowed the problem to the `respond_to` block and `format.html {redirect_to user_root_path}` line.

Comment: have u checked user_root route. Don't u need to pass user object id with this route.

Comment: `user_root_path` is a devise route. devise allows me to get the `current_user` without having to do a find(:id). `user_root_path` points to the correct route i.e. "/dashboard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in Billy Chan's answer, the url is "/gcal_user.19", so that means the controller is trying to respond to the format with type '19'. Try redefining your routes as `resources :gcal_user`, and you can pass `only: :destroy` if you wish to remove unneeded routes. I would have replied as a comment, but I don't have the required reputation to do so yet.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for explaining it. Simply having singular vs plural resource caused so much grief! Should I be always using plural resources for routes then?

Comment: The difference between the singular vs the plural is explained very well in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). Basically, the plural expects that you will be creating multiple resources of one type, and the singular expects only one resource of that type to ever be created. Most of the time you will use the plural form, but the singular form is useful in some cases too.

Comment: I don't think its explained well in the guides. I interpreted the explanation as a way to mask the "/profile/:id" route to "/profile" for the current logged in user but doesn't mean there's only one user ever in the app. Then it gives an example of geocoder but no clarification that its going to be only one geocoder ever like the way you phrased it. Thanks for clarifying it, really appreciate it.

Comment: @jvperrin, you hit the tail. @HM1, I suggest to use `resource` when possible, and dot(`.`) is a big smell in url

Answer (score 2):

"406" error represents for lack of right format to respond.

You do not have right format to respond because your controller action results an error, and the error has no format.

Why error? You `delete` method failed.

Why failed? You don't have an id assigned to the obj.

Why no id? You have not defined it in your routes.

See your routes. It's wrong

```
DELETE /gcal_user(.:format)              gcal_users#destroy
```

There is no id. The right things should be

```
DELETE /gcal_user/:id(.:format)              gcal_users#destroy
```

Try check and redefine your routes.

Comment: I believe the routes is like that because I used `resource :gcal_user` instead of `resources :gcal_user`. I might be wrong but I don't think that's the issue because the URL contains the id i.e. "/gcal_user.19" where 19 is the `:id`. Verified `params[:id] = 19` too. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not called with DELETE method and hence the destroy is not called. What is called is the Users#destroy with GET method and it is giving 406 error. The possible causes and their solution is given by Intrepidd above.

Try something like this:-

devise_scope :user do
root :to => 'home#dashboard'
end

Comment: I'm aware URL is not called with DELETE method... unobtrusive js converts it. I confirmed as stated above the `destroy` method is called and the code in it executes. Problem occurs at `respond_to` block. I don't see Intrepidd's answer!

Comment: Please dump your config/routes.rb here.

Comment: I added the routes.rb file above in the question so others can see it.